# how to detect if an object is hit by a certain raycast in it's own code

Tags: unity, javascript

I have been working on a sandbox game in Unity, and I am wanting to use a raycast on the cursor, but I am needing for the blocks themmselves to detect whether the cursor's raycast is hitting. I am needing the code in javaScript. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you're using an ordinary mouse cursor and your objects have colliders, then the built-in MonoBehaviour messages [OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) / [OnMouseOver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) / [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) should be able to do this for you, without doing your own raycasting or state management. Does that apply to your case?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to:

1. [Detect if the user clicked the mouse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)
2. [Convert the mouse to a world Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)
3. [Fire a raycast with the Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)
4. [Use the RaycastHit object to determine if hit.collider.gameObject == this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)

This will end up in, when the player clicks their mouse, will fire a raycast from their mouse and determine if it hits the object that the script is running on (hence the `RaycastHit.collider.gameObject`). Using [LayerMasks](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) might also be helpful in optimizing your search.

Comment: Yes, but how do I detect the raycast in the script of the block?

Comment: You'd put a script on the block doing the four steps above and have a public variable with the player's camera attached to be able to fire the raycasts. Therefore you can fire raycasts and determine if they hit the block itself. It would probably be a better solution to do this on the player and then notify the block it hits (by testing to see whether `hit.collider.gameObject`) has a `Block` component on it and then calling a function to notify it. This eliminates the need to fire a raycasts per `Block` in your scene.

Comment: @TheMattBat999 Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you, so other users can see at a glance that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

add some event to block which is called on that block, or add some field to manager that stores last clicked block and then block can check if Manager.lastClicked = this, then it's clicked